# Github icon in latex

Tags: cv

I have resume template on overleaf. Now I want to add github logo on that after linkdein logo. How can I do that?

https://www.overleaf.com/articles/aditya-gadepallis-resume/kzdksnkdcrsr

How I want to add github logo after linkdein logo.

I am confused how to do that can someone please help me in that.

This is the tex file : https://pastebin.com/qVJ7HViy

This is the cls file : https://pastebin.com/AX27WY7e

```
\ProvidesClass{twentysecondcv}[2017/01/08 CV class]
\LoadClass{article}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    REQUIRED PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{ifmtarg}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{pgffor}
\RequirePackage{marvosym}
\RequirePackage{parskip}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    COLOURS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
\definecolor{sidecolor}{HTML}{E7E7E7}
\definecolor{mainblue}{HTML}{0E5484}
\definecolor{maingray}{HTML}{B9B9B9}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    MISC CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\color{gray}} % Make \textbf produce coloured text instead

\pagestyle{empty} % Disable headers and footers

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % Disable paragraph indentation

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    SIDEBAR DEFINITIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm} % Left margin
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm} % Top margin

\newlength\imagewidth
\newlength\imagescale
\pgfmathsetlength{\imagewidth}{5cm}
\pgfmathsetlength{\imagescale}{\imagewidth/600}

\newlength{\TotalSectionLength} % Define a new length to hold the remaining line width after the section title is printed
\newlength{\SectionTitleLength} % Define a new length to hold the width of the section title
\newcommand{\profilesection}[1]{%
    \setlength\TotalSectionLength{\linewidth}% Set the total line width
    \settowidth{\SectionTitleLength}{\huge #1 }% Calculate the width of the section title
    \addtolength\TotalSectionLength{-\SectionTitleLength}% Subtract the section title width from the total width
    \addtolength\TotalSectionLength{-2.22221pt}% Modifier to remove overfull box warning
    \vspace{8pt}% Whitespace before the section title
    {\color{black!80} \huge #1 \rule[0.15\baselineskip]{\TotalSectionLength}{1pt}}% Print the title and auto-width rule
}

% Define custom commands for CV info
\newcommand{\cvdate}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvdate}{#1}}

\newcommand{\cvnumberphone}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvnumberphone}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvaddress}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvaddress}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvsite}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvsite}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Education}[1]{\renewcommand{\Education}{#1}}
\newcommand{\skills}[1]{\renewcommand{\skills}{#1}}
\newcommand{\COURSEWORK}[1]{\renewcommand{\COURSEWORK}{#1}}


\newcommand{\cvname}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvname}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cvjobtitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvjobtitle}{#1}}

% Command for printing the contact information icons
\newcommand*\icon[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt, fill=mainblue,mainblue,text=white] (char) {#1};}}

% Command for printing skill progress bars


% Command for printing skills text
\newcommand\skillstext[1]{ 
    \renewcommand{\skillstext}{
        \begin{flushleft}
            \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}{ 
                \x$ \star $\y
            }
        \end{flushleft}
    }
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    SIDEBAR LAYOUT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\makeprofile}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node [rectangle, fill=sidecolor, anchor=north, minimum width=9cm, minimum height=\paperheight+1cm] (box) at (-5cm,0.5cm){};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    %------------------------------------------------

    \begin{textblock}{6}(0.5, 0.2)

        %------------------------------------------------

        \ifthenelse{\equal{\profilepic}{}}{}{
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\imagescale,y=-\imagescale]
                    \clip (600/2, 567/2) circle (567/2);
                    \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{\profilepic}};
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{center}
        }

        %------------------------------------------------

        {\Huge\color{mainblue}\cvname}

        %------------------------------------------------

        {\Large\color{black!80}\cvjobtitle}

        %------------------------------------------------

        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm} @{\hskip 0.5cm}p{5cm}}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvdate}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Info}} & \cvdate\\}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvaddress}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Letter}} & \cvaddress\\}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvnumberphone}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Telefon}} & \cvnumberphone\\}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvsite}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Mundus}} & \cvsite\\}
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvmail}{}}{}{\textsc{\large\icon{@}} & \href{mailto:\cvmail}{\cvmail}}
        \end{tabular}

        %------------------------------------------------

        \ifthenelse{\equal{\Education}{}}{}{
            \profilesection{Education}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \Education
            \end{flushleft}
        }

        %------------------------------------------------
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\skills}{}}{}{
            \profilesection{Skills}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \skills
            \end{flushleft}
        }

        \ifthenelse{\equal{\COURSEWORK}{}}{}{
            \profilesection{COURSEWORK}
            \begin{flushleft}
                \COURSEWORK
            \end{flushleft}
        }




        %------------------------------------------------

    \end{textblock}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    COLOURED SECTION TITLE BOX
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Command to create the rounded boxes around the first three letters of section titles
\newcommand*\round[2]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[anchor=north west, draw,rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=1.6pt, minimum size=5.5mm, text height=3.6mm, fill=#2,#2,text=white](char){#1};%
}

\newcounter{colorCounter}
\newcommand{\sectioncolor}[1]{%
    {%
        \round{#1}{
            \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
            maingray\or%
            mainblue\or%
            maingray\or%
            mainblue\or%
            maingray\or%
            mainblue\or%
            maingray\or%
            mainblue\or%
            maingray\or%
            mainblue\else%
            maingray\fi%
        }%
    }%
    \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    {%
        \color{gray}%
        \Large\sectioncolor{#1}%
    }
}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{
    \par\vspace{.5\parskip}{%
        \large\color{gray} #1%
    }
    \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    LONG LIST ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

% New environment for the long list
\newenvironment{twenty}{%
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
}

\newcommand{\twentyitem}[4]{%
    #1&\parbox[t]{0.83\textwidth}{%
        \textbf{#2}%
        \hfill%
        {\footnotesize#3}\\%
        #4\vspace{\parsep}%
    }\\
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    SMALL LIST ENVIRONMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

% New environment for the small list
\newenvironment{twentyshort}{%
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
}

\newcommand{\twentyitemshort}[2]{%
    #1&\parbox[t]{0.83\textwidth}{%
        \textbf{#2}%
    }\\
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    MARGINS AND LINKS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[left=7.6cm,top=0.1cm,right=1cm,bottom=0.2cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}

\RequirePackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE, could you please add your scripts within the site only? External links will die over-time.

Comment: You can use the [`fontawesome` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) and its `\faGithub` command.

Comment: @PaulGaborit But when I use them it goes to the right side of resume.
I want to be it in left just below linkedein.

Comment: I have not tested it, but using the mentioned `fontawesome` icon and adding it to the class and document as done with `\cvsite` in the template should work. The current template uses `\Mundus` from the `marvosym` package - you may consider replacing it with the LinkedIn symbol from Font Awesome as well then.

Comment: @doncherry That is no duplicate for this question about `twentysecondcv`, it is about `moderncv` ...

Comment: Well, your given code does not compile. Have you already changed that cv? If yes, please correct the contained errors, if not it would be better to use the original template from http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com which does compile. There was an version of this template `\ProvidesClass{twentysecondcv}[2015/02/28 CV class]` already containing github symbol, but I do not remember where you can down load it ... Nevertheless, please show an compiling code, then we can add `\cvgithub` ... BTW: This template is not very good, have you considered to use a better one?

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) with an reputation point of 15vormore and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓). Please see that that is the way here to say "Thank You for your Help"!

Answer (score 7):

As already pointed:

- add the command `\usepackage{fontawesome}` to Your preambula
- then use the macro `\faicon{}` in Your text.

For the full list of icons refer to [Font Awesome website](http://fontawesome.io/icons/).

Comment: Your link points to the documentation of Font Awesome 5, while the `fontawesome` package only supports Font Awesome 4.6. So it supports even less than the icons listed in the Font Awesome 4 documentation, e.g. `free-code-camp` doesn't work (That's documenting v4.7). To make all the icons from Font Awesome 5 available, use the `fontawesome5` package.

Answer (score 2):

Well, with using an working example of class `twentysecondcv` and the related code for the cv `mwe.tex` you need only to add the following code into the preamble (after `\documentclass`) of your cv code `mwe.tex`:

```
% <=====================================================================
\usepackage{fontawesome} % <================ for \faGithub github symbol
%\usepackage{etoolbox} % <====================== already loaded in class
\newcommand{\cvgithub}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvgithub}{#1}}
\patchcmd{\makeprofile}%
{%search
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvsite}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Mundus}} & \cvsite\\}%
}
{%replace
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvsite}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Mundus}} & \cvsite\\}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvgithub}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\faGithub} & \cvgithub\\}
}%
{}%success
{}%failure
% <=====================================================================
```

That results in the following pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

Or you can use command `\icon` to get the blue circle:

```
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvgithub}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\faGithub}} & \cvgithub\\}
```

with the result:

[image: resultig pdf 2]

You can try the following mwe:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Twenty Seconds Resume/CV
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.1 (8/1/17)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Carmine Spagnuolo (cspagnuolo@unisa.it) with major modifications by
% Vel (vel@LaTeXTemplates.com)
%
% License:
% The MIT License (see included LICENSE file)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper]{twentysecondcv} % a4paper for A4

% <=====================================================================
\usepackage{fontawesome} % <================ for \faGithub github symbol
%\usepackage{etoolbox} % <====================== already loaded in class
\newcommand{\cvgithub}[1]{\renewcommand{\cvgithub}{#1}}
\patchcmd{\makeprofile}%
{%search
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvsite}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Mundus}} & \cvsite\\}%
}
{%replace
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvsite}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\Mundus}} & \cvsite\\}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\cvgithub}{}}{}{\textsc{\Large\icon{\faGithub}} & \cvgithub\\}
}%
{}%success
{}%failure
% <=====================================================================


\profilepic{example-image.png} % <======================================
\cvname{Aditya} % Your name
\cvjobtitle{Gadepalli} % Job title/career

\cvdate{16 February 1997} % Date of birth
\cvaddress{adityagadepalli@gmail.com} % Short address/location, use \newline if more than 1 line is required
\cvnumberphone{+91 9553336954} % Phone number
\cvsite{linkedin.com/in/a-gadepalli} % Personal website
\cvmail{john.doe@email.com} % <=========================================
\COURSEWORK{Coursework} % <=============================================
\cvgithub{github.com/user/theme} % Personal github


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    Education
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\Education{B.E.(Hons.) Mechanical Engineering BITS Pilani | 2018 | GPA:8.947/10
\newline \newline Class XII \newline  Mahathi Jr College | 2014 | 95.7 \%
\newline \newline Class X \newline  Rishi Vid. Gurukulam | 2012 | 10/10} % To have no Education section, just remove all the text and leave \Education{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    SKILLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Skill bar section, each skill must have a value between 0 an 6 (float)
\skills{Languages: C, Java, Matlab, SQL, Gosu, Basics of R and Python
\newline  WebDev : HTML, CSS, JS, JQuery, php  
\newline  Simulation :  Ansys, Comsol, Arduino
\newline  Design : ProE, AutoCAD, Solidworks, Autodesk Alias, Adobe Photoshop
\newline  Other: MS Office, JIRA, Git, Adobe AE
\newline Certifications: Oracle Certified Associate, Java SE 8 Programmer}



%\ExtraCurricular{Co-Founder \& Head @ Evolve  \\ - Organized talks \& workshops
%\\ - Brought the alumni of IITs, BITS, NITs and industry professionals to guide students
%\newline\newline Graphic Designer @ Designers Anonymous \& Dept. of Technical Arts\\- Taught design softwares to students\\- Designed content to publicize fests
%\newline \newline Event Manager @ BITS Embryo \\ - Organizer of conclave forums \& talks\\
%- Handled logistics \& pitched speakers
%\newline\newline Volunteer @ NSS \& Nirmaan NGO \\ - Created jobs for rural women\\- Co-organized Cyclone relief fund-raiser, cleanliness drives \& taught rural school kids
%\newline\newline Class Committee representative \& Teaching Assistant for the courses Production Techniques \& Human Resource Development}

%------------------------------------------------

% Skill text section, each skill must have a value between 0 an 6


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeprofile % Print the sidebar

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Work Experience and Internships}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
    \twentyitem{Since Aug'18}{Senior Analyst}{Capgemini, Hyderabad}{Building a Rating Engine for Insurance firms using Guidewire \& Java}
    \twentyitem{Jan-Jun'18}{Research Intern}{Center for AI \& Robotics, DRDO,  Bengaluru}{Designed \& built a Stair Climber bot along with its basic SDK library\\ Worked on Active Noise Cancellation algorithms for Wall Climber bot}
    \twentyitem{July'17}{Summer Intern}{NTPC Limited, Solapur}{Analyed \emph{Scope of Wind capacity installations} using Meteorological data and learnt about the practical challenges of commissioning them}
    \twentyitem{June'17}{Summer Intern}{RINL, Visakhapatnam}{Learnt about steel making processes \& waste heat recovery systems\\ Analyzed workflow \& suggested optimization of few bottlenecks}

    \twentyitem{Summer'16}{Summer Intern}{Century Rayon, Mumbai}{Investigated the "Heating Effects in Cake conditioning Rooms"\\
Studied TQM and DMAIC  practices to address performance issues}


    %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    PUBLICATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Research and Projects}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a short list with no descriptions
    \twentyitem{May-Dec'17}{Advanced Materials for Energy Efficient Buildings} {}{Studied the application of Phase Change Materials in buildings to \\reduce cooling load \& energy usage across various geographies}
    \twentyitem{Jan-May'17}{Design of Cleanroom for MEMS Fabrication}{}{Optimized the control parameters of an ISO 5 Cleanroom using DOE methods \& COMSOL5.1 (CFD) \& validated results with Hemair SI Ltd.}
    \twentyitem{Jan-May'17}{Interactive Creation of Splines}{}{Formulated algorithms and built a GUI using Matlab to obtain splines and their respective blending functions for any given dynamic input}
    \twentyitem{Aug-Nov'16}{Fabrication of Tabletop EDM Machine}{}{Led a team of 8 students to design \& build the product from genesis \&
achieved 20 micron erosion on AISI 1020 steel using brass electrode}
    \twentyitem{Aug-Nov'15}{Critical analysis of Performance appraisal systems}{}{Led a team of 8 students to survey \& review the appraisal systems of NTPC and IBM to measure its influence on employee's work outputs}
    %\twentyitemshort{<dates>}{<title/description>}
\end{twenty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    AWARDS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Achievements}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a short list with no descriptions
    \twentyitem{Dec'17}{Book Distribution Campaign}{}{Single handedly ran a campaign \& sold over 150+ books within 3 days}
    \twentyitem{Mar'17}{First - VIKAS Soch Ideation Marathon}{}{Won 10k in cash for best social startup idea at Launchpad E-Summit}
    \twentyitem{Mar'16}{Runners Up - Ground Reality}{}{Won 12k in cash for the best B-Plan submission at Pearl 2017}
    \twentyitem{Feb'10}{Best All Rounder Award}{}{Ranked first across all campuses of school for all-round excellence}
    \twentyitem{2010-11}{Olympiads(School Level)}{}{GOLD Medals won at NSO(2011), NCO(2010) \& IMO(2010))}
    %\twentyitemshort{<dates>}{<title/description>}
\end{twenty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%    EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Electives and MOOCs}

\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions

    \twentyitem{Electives}{Reverse Engineering \& Rapid Prototyping, Renewable Energy, Quality Control Assurance \& Reliability, Project Appraisal, Public Policy,\\Principles of Management, HR Development, Fundamentals of\\Finance \& Accounting, Srimad Bhagavad Gita}{}{}
    \twentyitem{MOOCs}{\textbf{Introduction to R,SQL \& Python Courses on Datacamp}\\Currently pursuing Deep Learning Specialization on Coursera}{}{}

    %\twentyitem{<dates>}{<title>}{<location>}{<description>}
\end{twenty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```